# Find an inverse in a quotient of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know this question is so easy that should be a first year algebra, but It has been a long time since I last studied this argument.

> I have to find the inverse of $x+2$ in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\left<x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1\right>$.

I tried to divide $(x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1)+1$ for $x + 2$ but I obtained a reminder of $86$. Then I tried to solve 
$$(x + 2)(ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f)=q(x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1)+1$$
and obtained that q must be a complex number. So now I'm wondering if there's a better way to proceed. Can anybody give me an hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *Horner's scheme* to divide by $x+2$:
$$\begin{matrix}\\\\\times -2\end{matrix}\quad\begin{matrix}
1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
&-2&4&-10&20&-42&84 \\
\hline
1&-2&5&-10&21&-42&\!\!\vert\; 85
\end{matrix}$$
Thus $\;x^6+x^4+x^2+1=(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)(x+2)+85$, so that
\begin{align}-\frac1{85}(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)(x+2)&=1-(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)\\&\equiv 1\mod (x^6+x^4+x^2+1).
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Equate co-efficients of each power of x and you get the following equations:

$a=q$

$2a+b=0$

$2b+c=q$

$2c+d=0$

$2d+e=q$

$2e+f=0$

$2f=q+1$

Then solve the equations to find a,b,c,d,e,f and q.

Comment: This is what I've done

Comment: Can also be that I just made an error in calculations

Comment: Indeed... thanks, was just an error in the calculations

Answer (score 1):

You can write $x^6+x^4+x^2+1=(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)(x+2)+85$

So, from here, $85=(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)-(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)(x+2)$, i.e.,

$85\equiv -(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)(x+2) \pmod{x^6+x^4+x^2+1}$

So, $(x+2)^{-1}=-\frac1{85}(x^5-2x^4+5x^3-10x^2+21x-42)$ in the quotient ring.